# Setting a breakpoint on a member function called on a specific object

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

In gdb, is it possible to set a breakpoint on a member function called on a specific object? To be more specific, imagine class A has a member function Foo(). I'd like the program to stop when Foo is called on a specific object of type A (0xFF11DEADBEAF for example).

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use: `b <Classname>::<functionname> if this==0xDEADBEEF` (btw: all instances share member function addresses.)